# Player class returning null 0 null

Tags: java, class, encapsulation

I created a player with: `Player player = new Player(hand, 5000, "Player_1");`

When printing class it prints "null 0 null"

Why are the variables not being saved? Thanks!

Player class:

```
public class Player {
    private Hand hand; //hand with 5 cards
    private int chips; //chips left
    private String name; //name of player

    public Player (Hand hand, int chips, String name) {
        hand = this.hand;
        chips = this.chips;
        name = this.name;
    }

    public int getChips() {
        return chips;
    }

    public Hand getHand() {
        return hand;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + chips + " " + hand;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at your constructor - you're assigning the instance values (`this.hand`) to the parameters you're passing in.  The assignment should be the other way around (ie `this.hand = hand`)

Answer (score 2):

> *"... Why are the variables not being saved? ..."*

In your constructor method, you have the assignment's reversed.

```java
public Player (Hand hand, int chips, String name) {
    hand = this.hand;
    chips = this.chips;
    name = this.name;
}
```

It should be, the following.

```java
public Player (Hand hand, int chips, String name) {
    this.hand = hand;
    this.chips = chips;
    this.name = name;
}
```

In this situation, the *this* keyword is used to differentiate the instance variables from the local variables.

*[Using the this Keyword (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Classes and Objects)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)*.